# Prestashop : url rewrite not working

Tags: php, macos, apache, url-rewriting, prestashop

PhpInfo shows that the Apache Rewrite module is activated.

In the backoffice the simplified URLS option is activated.

But still urls are in the form of index.php?q=user

What could be other possible reasons for this?

Comment: try deleting the .htaccess file in the prestashop root and replacing it with aan empty one and set approriate permissions, then disable freindly urls, save, enable them again and save.

Comment: this helped. in the end it was a db issue

Comment: @MisterFresh which issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the webserver are write permission on Prestashop installation directory. I fit do not, it will not be able to write down the `.htaccess` file.